# Augmentated ideal when the group has a system of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, group-rings

I will start by giving some context. I am currently studying the augmentation morphism $\varepsilon: \mathbb{Z}[G] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that maps each formal sum to the sum of each components. Plugging in the equality $g = g - e + e$ (where $g \in G$ and $e \in G$ is the neutral element of the group) in a formal sum $\sum{n_g \cdot g}$, one can easily show that $Ker \varepsilon$ is generated by all the elements of the form $g-e$, with $g \in G$.

I was wondering if there is a stronger statement for the case where $G$ has a system of generators $S$, i.e. if $G$ is generated by $S$, is $Ker \varepsilon$ generated by elements of the form $s - e$, where $s \in S$? And if so, how is the proof done? Because the aforementioned technique doesn't seem to work. Also, in both cases, is this way of generating $Ker \varepsilon$ a $\mathbb{Z}-$basis of $Ker \varepsilon$?

Comment: You could read section 3.3 of "An Introduction to Group Rings", by Milies and Sehgal. They talk about some sort of general approach to the augmentation map and present some results you might like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you define the kernel of $\varepsilon$ (= what category do you consider this morphism to be in)? By the way, its definition doesn't seem right (or are the 'components' just the $n_g$'s?)

---

The word "generated" means two different things here: "two-sided ideal generated as $\Bbb Z$-module" and "group generated as ..." well, a group. Take $G = C_n$ (cyclic of $n$ elements). Then the lattice $\Bbb Z[G]$ is $n$-dimensional, the kernel of $\varepsilon$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional and clearly can't be generated as a $\Bbb Z$-span of $\alpha-e$, where $\alpha$ is the generator of $G$.

As for being a basis, suppose otherwise and get by moving the subtrahends that the LHS is a $\Bbb Z$-"linear" combination of group elements $\not = 1$, and the RHS is a multiple of $1$. By definition of group ring that's only possible when the "linear" combinations are all trivial.

Comment: I consider $\varepsilon$ to be a morphism from group rings to the abelian group formed by the integers. Sorry, could you explain again why is the definition not right?

Comment: Thank you for the example! As for the basis part, how does the last part follow from the definition of group ring?

Comment: If by components you mean coefficients of the group elements, then everything is fine. The group ring as a $\Bbb Z$-module is a *free* module on the group elements, isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^{|G|}$. The elements of the basis in the free module do not satisfy any additive relations except the ones that follow from the $\Bbb Z$-module axioms.